# jquery toggle hover items with hide delay

Tags: jquery

I put this code together from a snippet from somewhere else, so I may not be doing this very well.
I have multiple div's that looks like this:

```
<div class="services">
<p>...</p>
<ol class="serviceList" style="display: none;">
  <li>
    <p>service</p>
    <ul>
      <li>service description</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
...
</ol>
</div>
```

I want the `<ol>` to `slideDown` when the services `div` is hovered over. It needs a delay so that it doesn't vanish if the user mistakenly mouseout. BUT if they mouse over another services `div` then the visible one needs to go away immediately to make room for the new `serviceList` Here is what I have now:

```
$('.services').each(function () {
            var time = 800;
            var hideDelay = 1000;

            var hideDelayTimer = null;

            var beingShown = false;
            var shown = false;
            var trigger = $(this);
            var info = $('.serviceList', this);

            $([trigger.get(0),info.get(0)]).mouseover(function () {


                if (hideDelayTimer) clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
                if (beingShown || shown) {
                    // don't trigger the animation again

                    return;
                } else {



            info.addClass('active');

                    // reset position of info box
                    beingShown = true;

                    info.css('zindex','2')
                    .slideDown(time, function() {
                        beingShown = false;
                        shown = true;
                    });
                }

                return false;
            }).mouseout(function () {

                if (hideDelayTimer) clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
                hideDelayTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                    hideDelayTimer = null;

                    info.css('zindex','0')
                    .fadeOut( hideDelay, function () {
                        shown = false;
                        info.removeClass('active');
                    });


                }, hideDelay);

                return false;
            });


        });
```

I have a poor understanding of scope so I don't know what the get(0) stuff is about. I've been trying to have an event on mouseover that checks if any other "serviceList" is `.active` and then hide it. That works, unless you switch between "services" too fast. Am even close to doing this right?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try using the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin.  This is what it is designed for.

```
$('.services').hoverIntent(
     function() { // over
        $(this).find('.serviceList:first').slideDown();
     },
     function() { // out
        $(this).find('.serviceList:first').slideUp();
     }
);
```

Note that this is basically the same as the [hover()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover#overout) method, but it includes the delay that you are looking for.

Comment: Note: I changed the traversal method as the list is a child of the DIV not a sibling.